# NGINX + Gunicorn: zero size buf in writer

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

we've run into a weird issue with NGINX and Gunicorn (serving pages from Django) and can't really figure out where to look next.

**The problem:** The problem is that some seemingly random URLs of our site will return 502's instead of their correct content. After some unknown and again seemingly random amount of time the URL will return correctly again. This has happened repeatedly over a few months and over multiple different endpoints (some list routes, some detail routes, etc.)

**Relevant Architecture Setup:** Our site is running in AWS with an Elastic Load Balancer in front and various ECS containers in back. Each ECS Container has two tasks running in it, one NGINX task and one Gunicorn/Django task.

NGINX config:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 20000;  # max usable file descriptors, should be about double the worker_connections and less than the OS `nofile` ulimit

events {
    worker_connections 10000;
}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    upstream app-server {
        server app:8000;
    }

    log_format json_combined escape=json '{ "time_local": "$time_local", '
                                        '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
                                        '"request": "$request", '
                                        '"status": "$status", '
                                        '"message": "$remote_addr - $request - $status - $request_time - $body_bytes_sent - $http_user_agent", '
                                        '"forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for", '
                                        '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent", '
                                        '"request_time": "$request_time", '
                                        '"http_referrer": "$http_referer", '
                                        '"http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent" }';

    error_log stderr info;
    access_log /dev/stdout json_combined;

    server {
        listen 80;
        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

        client_max_body_size 50m;
        client_body_buffer_size 50m;

        server_name _;

        location /robots.txt {
            return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /usr/src/app/static/;
        }

        location / {
            # Trust any X-Forwarded-For headers from 10.*.*.* ip addresses
            set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
            real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
            real_ip_recursive on;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app-server;
        }
    }
}
```

**Troubleshooting steps taken/information discovered:**

1. Requesting the exact same request in cURL without the `--compressed` argument results in the correct response instead of a 502. Requesting again with the compressed results in the 502 again.
2. NGINX is logging a similar message to the following on each occurance: `2019/10/07 19:12:09 [alert] 7#7: *42088 zero size buf in writer t:1 r:1 f:0 00005567E6F4CDF0 00005567E6F4CDF0-00005567E6F4CDF0 0000000000000000 0-0 while sending to client, client: [IP REDACTED], server: _, request: "GET /v2/shipments/[ID REDACTED]/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[IP REDACTED]:8000/v2/shipments/[ID REDACTED]/", host: "[HOSTNAME REDACTED]", referrer: "https://[HOSTNAME REDACTED]/shipments/[ID REDACTED]"`
3. NGINX also reports it's returning a 200 but no body: `{ "time_local": "07/Oct/2019:19:12:09 +0000", "remote_addr": "[IP REDACTED]", "request": "GET /v2/shipments/[ID REDACTED]/ HTTP/1.1", "status": "200", "message": "[IP REDACTED] - GET /v2/shipments/[ID REDACTED]/ HTTP/1.1 - 200 - 0.811 - 0 - Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36", "forwarded_for": "[IP REDACTED], [IP REDACTED], [IP REDACTED]", "body_bytes_sent": "0", "request_time": "0.811", "http_referrer": "https://[HOSTNAME REDACTED]/shipments/[ID REDACTED]", "http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36" }`
4. Gunicorn reports no errors and appears to be completing everything correctly.
5. We've effectively ruled out the ELB since we're able to reproduce the issue by going into our VPC and calling the ECS containers directly and reproducing the issue.
6. We thought perhaps it was an issue in compressing some character or series of characters, however having Django serve just the payload returned without the `--compressed` flag does not reproduce the issue.
7. The issue is not specific to a particular ECS container. When an endpoint is experiencing it, it occurs across all containers.

**Specific help needed:** Where to look next for troubleshooting. We've tried searching around for the NGINX message (zero size buf in writer), however most of these just tell us that it's an upstream issue, however Gunicorn is reporting that everything is going without issue, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to look next.

Answer (score 1):

For future people finding this question, the solution was upgrading to NGINX 1.17.3+ as detailed here: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1826